# Как прервать запущенный метод, при нажатии кнопки

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qtimer

Как прервать запущенный метод (в моем случае `add_str_num`), при нажатии кнопки Отмена(`pushButton2`).

я сделал с помощью `stop`, для него добавил метод `click` где он меняет свое значение на `True` и в методе добавил условие по которому метод прекращает работать. Не знаю почему оно не работает, как нужно сделать?

```
import design
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.input_file = ''
        self.stop = False

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.select_a_file)
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.add_str_num)
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.click)

    def select_a_file(self):
        self.file_input, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выбор файла', '')
        self.label.setText(self.file_input)

    def click(self):
        self.stop = True

    def add_str_num(self):

        self.step = 0
        num = 100000
        pace = 100 / num
        with open(self.file_input) as f:
            text = f.read()
            for i in range(num):
                text += str(i) + 'helloworld'
                self.step += pace
                self.progressBar.setValue(round(self.step))

                if self.stop:
                    self.stop = false
                    self.progressBar.setValue(0)
                    return

        with open(self.file_input, 'w') as p:
            p.write(text)
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Example()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

вот design.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:/Users/PC/1/design.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(165, 148)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(165, 148))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(165, 148))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"background-color: rgb(35, 75, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 10, 91, 21))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 41, 31))
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.btn.setObjectName("btn")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 101, 21))
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 100, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton2")
        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 70, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton1")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Select \n"
" a file"))
        self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Отмена"))
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как можно обойтись без многопоточности?

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста модуль `design.py`

Comment: Не работает потому, что функция click будет вызвана только после того, как завершится выполнение add_str_num. Вам нужна многопоточность

Comment: как можно обойтись без многопоточности?

Comment: 1. Можно завести простой текстовый файл (запись в реестре?) и на каждом цикле открывать его и проверять не написано ли в нем Stop, не забывая закрывать в конце цикла и делать паузу, чтобы двуногий успел туда что-нибудь записать. 1.1 База данных? 2. Можно посылать команду по-сети 3. Можно установить таймер со случайным временем срабатывания 4. Можно вырубать приложение из памяти 5. Можно ресетить компутер. А можно просто пойти почитать про многопоточность - прокачать скилы, получить + в карму, познать дзен

Comment: может быть есть другие способы, как сделать без многопоточности? чтобы он обнулял все запущенные процессы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все можно сделать. Вам дали много советов, самый правильный освоит многопоточность! По использованию многопоточности опубликовано много постов, поэтому надо не бояться, а читать и пробовать!

Но если вам так хочется без многопоточности, тогда `QTimer` вам в помощь. Я также добавил некоторые правильный вещи. Пробуйте.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog


#from design import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(165, 148)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(165, 148))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(165, 148))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"background-color: rgb(35, 75, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 10, 91, 21))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 41, 31))
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.btn.setObjectName("btn")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 101, 21))
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 100, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton2")
        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 70, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton1")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Select \n"
" a file"))
        self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Отмена"))
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.input_file = ''
        self.stop = False

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.select_a_file)
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.add_str_num)
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.stop_click)

        self.file_input = None                                              # +++
        self.text = ''                                                      # +++
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)                                    # QTimer
        self.timer.setInterval(5)                                           # QTimer setInterval
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self._timeout)                           # QTimer self._timeout

    def select_a_file(self):
        self.file_input, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выбор файла', '')
        self.label.setText(self.file_input)

    def stop_click(self):
        if not self.timer.isActive():                                       # QTimer isActive
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'Message', 'Расчет не был запущен, отменять нечего.')
            return
        self.timer.stop()                                                   # QTimer stop
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
        with open(self.file_input, 'w') as p:
            p.write(self.text)

    def add_str_num(self):
        if not self.file_input:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'Message', 'Выберите файл для чтения.')
            return
        with open(self.file_input) as f:
            self.text = f.read()
        self.step = 0
        self.num = 10000 #0
        self.pace = 100 / self.num
        self.i = 0
        self.timer.start()                                                   # QTimer start

    def _timeout(self):                                                      # +++ !!!
        if self.i < self.num:
            self.text += str(self.i) + ' helloworld\n'                       # + \n
            self.step += self.pace
            self.i += 1
            self.progressBar.setValue(round(self.step))
        else:
            self.stop_click()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Example()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо)